# Theme (from scratch) Wordpress doesn't work properly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I created a test theme from scratch, and i have a few problems with the stylesheet.

This is how my directory looks: [image]
[image]

and this is the code:

**index.php**

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>this is a test Carolina WP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/carodev/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>this is a phrase </p>
    <img src="ressources/womanicon.png">
  </div>

    <div class="services-container">
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service-preview">
                <h6>Services</h6>
                <h2>Depannage</h2>
                <a href="#">autres services <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-info">
                <div class="progress-container">
                    <div class="progress"></div>
                    <span class="progress-text">
                        Trés demandé
                    </span>
                </div>
                <h2>Votre ordinateur <br>
                    ne marche pas ?</h2>
                <button class="btn">Contact-nous</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">

        <img src="./ressources/womanicon.png">
        <img src="../womanicon.png">
        <img src="../ressources/womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
        <img src="womanicon.png">
</div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

**style.css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #7175da, #9790F2);
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.service {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;
}

.service h6 {
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.service-preview {
    background-color: #2A265F;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

.service-preview a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.service-info {
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.progress-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
}

.progress {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.progress::after {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #2A265F;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 66%;
}

.progress-text {
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #2A265F;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
    ". . ."
    ". . ."
    ". . ."
    ". . .";
}`
```

The first error that i was getting : ERROR: 404 not found 1:style.css

But when in the url i specify de style.css ex: Localhost:8888/test/style.css it worked.
After that I put the container with pictures, but pictures weren't loading.

And now I have this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the WordPress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/#required-files) for theme development. As per the document, your file name should be **style.css** instead of **styles.css**

After renaming, your stylesheet name your error will solve but this is not the right way to include files.

You need to create a **functions.php** file in your theme directory. Put the below code into your **functions.php** file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Then, please add the below code on top of your **index.php** file for load header template.

```
<?php
  get_header();
?>
```

Comment: Hey krunal Bhimajiyani, ty so much for your answer. I forgot to rename the file, I changed it to "styles.css" to see if something would change, and forgot to re-change it, ty so much, now the error has dissapear. I thought I could enqueue it like a normal html <link<, ty so much for the info ! :) Have a good day !

Comment: I'm glad to help! Wishing you a good day as well :)